# Weird window.open behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This code behaves funny on Chrome (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwnxq/)):

```
try {
   open('6:-=');
} catch(e) {}
```

First, despite the code being wrapped in a try-catch, an error is thrown:

> Unable to open a window with invalid URL '%36:%04-='.

Second, extraneous characters are inserted in the URL, namely `%3` and `%04`.

Why doesn't the try-catch intercept the error, and why does the URL have those extra characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle contains a non-printable character with ASCII code 4 in the `6:-=` string after the colon, which is URL-encoded as `%04` in the displayed error. In addition, the `6:` part of the provided URL is interpreted as an URL scheme, which cannot start with a digit, so apparently Chrome URL-quotes the 6 as `%36` as well, although such behavior is not prescribed by the RFC.

Answer (score 5):

The `try`/`catch` doesn't have any effect because it's not an exception. It's merely an [error message](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.cpp&exact_package=chromium&type=cs&l=1799) printed to the console. You can proof that:

```
open('6:-=');
console.log(1);  // logged as usual
```

Basically, it's just like `console.error()` doesn't throw an exception either, yet it prints an exception-like message to the console.

Comment: Thanks. How did you generate the link, with line number and all?

Comment: @Randomblue: Click on the line number :o)

Answer (score 2):

First: As pimvdb said, it's because it isn't actually an exception.

Second: %04 is an invisible character inserted by JSFiddle. %36 is the number 6 which Chrome converts to %36 when encoding it for URL scheme. [Updated fiddle without %04](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/Mwnxq/1/)

Comment: Heh, good catch. jsFiddle is really annoying when it comes to those characters.

Comment: @Randomblue JSFiddle inserts control characters into your code to keep track of where your code ends. Sometimes, when we add code to the end of a fiddle, the character stays in the code.

Comment: @Randomblue Oops, yeah. Added the wrong link. Check the edited link.